# Webhook Service for Dialogflow does not recieve any requests (Status 206)

Tags: apache, lets-encrypt, google-home, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es

I host a nodejs webservice to handle my Dialogflow Webhook requests.
I am using Express and I handle any POST-Requests (and first thing I do is loggin incoming POST-Requests to the console).

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const http = require('http');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.post('*', function(req, res) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
[...]
```

My NodeJS service is exposed to my domain through a Apache ReverseProxy (.htaccess) and I have a valid Let'sEncrypt SSL Certificate for my domain.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:63333/$1 [P]
```

When I test my Service through Postman I see the request being logged on the node console and the correct response being sent.

But when I want to use it in Dialogflow as Webhook Fulfillment, Dialogflow shows me this status and I don't even see a POST-Request coming into my Nodejs App / Console:

```
  [...]
  "status": {
    "code": 206,
    "errorType": "partial_content",
    "errorDetails": "Webhook call failed. Error: Webhook response was empty.",
    "webhookTimedOut": false
  }
  [...]
```

In my opinion at least a request should come to my Server?
Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you see the hit in the Apache logs? Can you confirm that the fulfillment URL you have set in Dialogflow is an HTTPS URL and the URL is publicly reachable? (And share with us any details if possible?)

Comment: Yes it is a HTTPS URL and it is publicly reachable (proven through Postman).

Let me check the Apache logs.

Comment: No, there is no request nor error logged by Dialogflow. Only my Postman requests.

But I entered the same URL in Dialogflow as Webhook as I use in Postman ??

Comment: What, exactly, is the URL you used? (A screenshot of the Dialogflow fulfillment screen may be best.) (And yes, I saw what you posted in reply to my answer that I've deleted - I can reach that one.)

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/vVqgP) you can see the Dialogflow fulfillment screen. In the Default Welcome Intent the Webhook tick is set, too.

Comment: Try adding a trailing slash to that URL in the fulfillment field.

Comment: Does not change anything - unfortunately